# How to get all contain (all modules) of Site from my theme in Magento2

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I have create my theme From default magento-luma theme so luma is a parent them of my theme.

**Below is the Step that I followed to create my theme from luma**.

**1).** copy **theme-frontend-luma** folder from **vendor/magento** and place it to **app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name**.

**now onwards all below changes I have done in my theme folder.**

**2).** in **register.php** file I changed with my package name and theme name.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Forever/theme',
__DIR__
);
```

3). **theme.xml** file

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Forever Theme</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
```

Now I go to admin **content->design->themes** and I see that now my theme is showing there so I go to **store->configuration->general->design and assign my package and theme.

After that using **CMD** I run **magento setup:static-content:deploy** comment.

Now I go to frontend and what I see is yeah I done this. I have set up my theme for magento2 store.

but when I enable template path hint and see in frontend  some of the content (modules) are coming from vendor folder.so I have done some changes in vendor folder. So If I upgrade my magento version so will my changes remove?

Now what I want is below.

Like magento 1.x if we create theme from base folder then all modules are coming from our theme folder not from base I want same for magento 2.x And I don't want to come any module from vendor folder. so what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

To copy luma,blank theme or module templates, layout and web files to own custom theme

**1) To Copy template file:**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Follow this path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

**2) To Copy layout file:**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Follow this path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to do overrider those templates into your custom theme.

By default first go to your theme folder and get templates file if required templates are not found then they go to core **`magento/module-Vendor`** folder and fetch required templates from module.

So you have to either override into your theme folder or they fetch from required module.

You can override your module folder tempates to your theme like this,

Example, if YOu want to override `magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` then you have to create your custom theme.

For Overrider list.phtml file into your theme,
go to path , `app/design/frontend/templates/Packagename/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Now your list file is overriden by your theme.

Same as above any module file you can override.

Here `module-catalog` becomes inside our theme is `Magento_Catalog`.
Like override file of **`module-configurable-product`** template you have to create folder inside your theme like **`Magento_ConfigurableProduct`** and create **templates** folder and remaining path are same for templates.

Moreinfo you can check link, [Override Templates](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html)

Comment: How can I override all the template and layout from vendor to my theme?